# How to plot a line with more than 2 weight?

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, plot

So I have a dataset with this structure

**Input**

- Input: 2 inputs [x, y]
- Range: -99999 - 99999

**Output**

- Output: 4 output [0,0,0,1] (Onehot encoding)
- Range: 0 - 1

What I want to create is a simple Quadrant like this.
[image]

And I want to see how single layer perceptron is actually do it.

I Got this code from [here](https://nasirml.wordpress.com/2017/11/19/single-layer-perceptron-in-tensorflow/)

```
plot_x = np.array([np.min(x[:, 0] - 10), np.max(x[:, 1]) + 10])

#This is for 2 weights
plot_y = - 1 / W[1] * (W[0] * plot_x + b) # comes from, w0*x + w1*y + b = 0 then y = (-1/w1) (w0*x + b)

plt.scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1], c=y, s=100, cmap='viridis')
plt.plot(plot_x, plot_y, color='k', linewidth=2)
plt.xlim([-99999, 99999])
plt.ylim([-99999, 99999])
plt.show()
```

My question is, how do I calculate `plot_y` from these weights?

I'm (very) new in matplotlib and this is my first time trying to make a visualization.

From my understanding, plot_y will create a line to split the classification.

Comment: What do you want to achieve that the code does not already do?

Comment: The code is wrong (for `plot_y` formula), because I have 4 weights, while my x is only 2. See my `plot_x` np array is 1x2 dimension. while my weights is 1x4 dimension. (I can't multiply my matrix this way)